# Started learning Ruby from scratch, why is user_input equivalent to gets.chomp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started learning Ruby from scratch, from the preliminary preparation there is a certain knowledge of HTML and CSS. For training I use Code Academy. I have questions and can't always find an answer I can understand I need help understanding the following:

```
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
```

Explain why user_input is equivalent to gets.chomp and what that means, thanks in advance!

Comment: `user_input` is a reference to the return value of `gets.chomp`. `gets.chomp` returns the "chomped" value of `gets`. `chomp` removes the line terminator *(see https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp)*.

Comment: `user_input.downcase!` sets `user_input` to the lower-case version of whatever the results of the above were . So if you type in `"Hi there[RETURN]"` `user_input` will end up being `"hi there"`. That's all there is.

Comment: This code would be better written as `user_input = gets.chomp.downcase` since you're going to do the downcase anyway. It just gets it out of the way up front.

Comment: What do you mean by _is equivalent_? Aside from that, the comment by _tadman_ shows of course a better way to write it.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby `=` is used to assign values to variables, as in:

```
x = 1
y = x
```

Where `y` assumes the value of `x` at the moment that line is executed. This is not to be confused with "equivalence" as in `x=y` in a *mathematical* sense where you're establishing some kind of permanent relationship.

In Ruby methods return a value, even if that value is "nothing", or `nil`. In the case of `gets`, it returns a `String`. You can call `chomp` on that, or any other thing you need to achieve your objective, like chaining on `downcase`.

On its own `gets.chomp` will read a line of input, strip off the trailing linefeed character, and then throw the result in the trash. Assigning this to a variable preserves that output.

Answer (score 0):

To understand it, break it down first

- Accept user input
- Clean the user input (using chomp https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp)
- Downcase it

```rb
    user_input = gets # will return the value entered by the user
    user_input = user_input.chomp # will remove the trailing \n
    
    # A more idiomatic way to achieve the above steps in a single line
    user_input = gets.chomp

    # Finally downcase
    user_input.downcase!


    # By that same principle the entire code can be written in a single line
    user_input = gets.chomp.downcase
```

> user_input is equivalent to gets.chomp

Remember, everything in Ruby is an object. So gets returns a `String` object, so does `chomp` and so does `downcase`. Hence with this logic you are essentially calling instance methods on the `String` class

```
String.new("hello") == "hello" # true
# "hello".chomp is same as String.new("hello").chomp
```